# I just installed WSS 3.0 -- now what?

Tags: sharepoint, wss-3.0

I've been doing web (all ASP.NET now) and desktop development for ten years and have written half a dozen intranet CMS websites. Nobody at my shop has any SharePoint experience and I've been asked to investigate WSS 3.0 and answer questions like "Can we replace our current ASP.NET intranet with a WSS-based intranet portal server without losing all of the custom web apps we currently have," "Can we write workflow-driven apps with multi-step authorization quickly and easily (things like time-sheets and project requests)" and "how easy/hard will this be to manage?"

Oh -- and MOSS is off the table: it has to be WSS 3.0.

What resources are out there for experienced programmers -- who have never looked at WSS before -- to quickly get up to speed with what WSS offers, how to program for it, and how to manage it?

Comment: Exact dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1110341/getting-started-developing-for-sharepoint and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1141687/how-to-start-learning-sharepoint

Comment: @Parvenu74: Please search the site before asking questions that have been asked before. Thanks!

Comment: @Alex: If there had been a WSS specific question I wouldn't posted mine

Comment: @Parvenu74: Yes I understand it's confusing when you're getting started. Getting started with SharePoint always means getting started with WSS first. It's only once that's understood that learning MOSS is a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Free online course from Microsoft:
https://www.microsoftelearning.com/eLearning/courseDetail.aspx?courseId=61917&tab=overview

Windows SharePoint Services Developer Center:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/default.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Search this site for start+sharepoint, you'll find loads of similar questions.

Answer (score 0):

If MOSS is off the table, the answer to your boss's question is "no".